# Samsung WebApi API not Working on Tizen TV-4.0 Emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-tv

The Tizen tv-4.0 emulator is not running the apps properly. I am getting the error:

$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

although I'm loading the script in index.html

Does the tv-4.0 emulator not support the web apis? What's the difference from the simulator then?

How can I load the Web API's?

Comment: Can you show the line where you load the web API?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and decided to use the other TV profile. You should use the emulator with the profile of tv-samsung-4.0-x86, because it contents additional samsung Web API extensions. Good day!

Comment: i tried this but the template is missing when setting it up